# How can I force the C++ platform in MSBuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, vcxproj

I have a program which must build as 32 bit. It gets shipped with an x64 application. As a result, there is an installer which gets a bitness.

The installer is built with a `wixproj` that must be built with `/p:Platform=x64` -- but the `vcxproj` needs to build as x86.

I tried forcing `Platform` to be `x86` or `Win32` by setting it explicitly:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Platform>Win32</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but it appears that the command line switch that got passed to the `wixproj` "wins" when building.

Is there some way that the project file can force `Platform` to be `Win32` no matter what is specified on the command line?

(for `csproj` I was able to do this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but that doesn't have any effect on C++ it seems)

Comment: since youre asking this I assume you are not building them seperately - how are you building those project then? Are they part of a single solution? You use a master build file? Can you maybe show the msbuild part that invoked building each of them?

Comment: @stijn: `msbuild foo.wixproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured this out. MSBuild has a setting [`TreatAsLocalProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcxfsh87%28v=vs.121%29.aspx) that allows a project file to override any variable, which goes into the `Project` node at the beginning of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
         ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         TreatAsLocalProperty="Platform"> <!-- !!! -->
  <PropertyGroup>
     <Platform>Win32</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Now Platform is Win32 no matter what! -->
</Project>
```